# Insert n values in dataframe where n is described in other list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mapply

I have a dataframe `a` and a list `b`:

```
  a = data.frame(a = c(1:4), c = c(1:4), b = c(1:4) )
  b = c(4,3,4,5)
  names(b) = c("a","c","b", "d")

> a
  a c b
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4

>b
a c b d 
4 3 4 5
```

I want to insert in `a` n copies of each column where n is described by b[i]. In this example `a` should look like:

```
   a c b
1  1 1 1
2  1 1 1
3  1 1 1
4  1 1 1
5  2 2 2
6  2 2 2
7  2 2 2
8  3 3 3
9  3 3 3
10 3 3 3
11 3 3 3
12 4 4 4
13 4 4 4
14 4 4 4
15 4 4 4
16 4 4 4
```

I think this should be easy in R, but after much of experimentig with mapply function i could not get the wanted result.

Comment: What is the relation with names of columns in `a` and the names in vector `b`, from output it looks like there is no relation?

Comment: There is no relation between the names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a[rep(seq_along(b), b), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Package `splitstackshape` has a very useful function for expanding the rows of a data frame,

```
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(a, b, count.is.col = FALSE)
```